# Dynamic creation of a peer-peer socket (ZeroMQ)

Tags: sockets, zeromq

My purpose is to create dynamically some ZeroMQ sockets (peer-peer) in C.

I have one listen socket in my server and when a client sends a message I attribute a new port and create a connection with this new port and I return on my listen socket.

Ex:

- server listens to a port 8500
- client 1 sends a message to 8500
- server sends a new port number 8510
- server and client create a connection on the port 8510
  (the client breaks the connection on port 8500)
- server listens for other connections
- client 2 sends a message to 8500
- server sends a new port number 8511 ...

What type of ZeroMQ function should I use?

I was thinking about FD and select but maybe not compatible with ZeroMQ or of `zmq_poll()`, but it's confused in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What type of ZeroMQ function should I use?

Well, the scenario above will definitely use **many** functions for achieving that, yet the approach will depend on which native API version do you decide to use, which depends on what population of remote-agents would you like to let-in, let's assume a minimum level of 2.1+.

---

**Server side will most probably use all of these:**
- version self-check:  `zmq_version()`
- context instantiation:  `zmq_init()`
- context parametrisation:  *not present in all native API versions, check API docs*
- socket instantiation:  `zmq_socket()`
- socket setup:  `zmq_setsockopt()`
- socket transport-class lock-in on an infrastructure element `zmq_bind( { inproc://...| ipc://...| tcp://...:# | pgm://...:# | epgm://...:# | vmci://... } )`  *`vmci://` transport-class not being present in all native API-versions*
- message resources and state-management operations `[ zmq_msg_init(), zmq_msg_copy(), ..., zmq_msg_close() ]`
- socket "reading", best non-blocking, with a pre-"sniffing" poll `zmq_recv()` + `zmq_poll()`
- socket "sending", best non-blocking `zmq_send()`
- local "event"-loop with checking also `zmq_errno()` for a presence of error(s) and `zmq_strerror()` to make it a bit more human-readable
- socket resources release: `zmq_close()`
- context resources release: `zmq_term()`

---

**Client side will most probably use all of these:**
- version self-check:  `zmq_version()`
- context instantiation:  `zmq_init()`
- context parametrisation:  *not present in all native API versions, check API docs*
- socket instantiation:  `zmq_socket()`
- socket setup:  `zmq_setsockopt()`
- socket transport-class attempt to `zmq_connect()` local side to an exposed remote infrastructure element's Access Point using respective transport-class matching parameters `{ inproc://...| ipc://...| tcp://...:# | pgm://...:# | epgm://...:# | vmci://... } )`  *`vmci://` transport-class not being present in all native API-versions*
- message resources and state-management operations `[ zmq_msg_init(), zmq_msg_copy(), ..., zmq_msg_close() ]`
- socket "reading", best non-blocking, with a pre-"sniffing" poll `zmq_recv()` + `zmq_poll()`
- socket "sending", best non-blocking `zmq_send()`
- local "event"-loop with checking also `zmq_errno()` for a presence of error(s) and `zmq_strerror()` to make it a bit more human-readable
- socket resources release: `zmq_close()`
- context resources release: `zmq_term()`

---

### The best next step if *confused*, as reported above:

The best place to start - if indeed willing to dive into the professional [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system)'s design is to understand a Zen-of-Zero, as lovely presented in Pieter HINTJENS' book "Code Connected, Volume 1". Not an easy read, but worth time and efforts to start with.